# Converting python 2.7 Script to python 3.8

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have this python script in AWS that automatically creates snapshot backups for me.  I need to convert it from Python 2.7 to Python 3.8 and have updated the "Print" ('function') already as per other research, but can't find out why it still doesn't work.

It's work that I copied and pasted originally.   I do not know python code :) :(

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    import boto3
    import collections
    import datetime

    ec = boto3.client('ec2')

    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        reservations = ec.describe_instances(
            Filters=[
                {'Name': 'tag-key', 'Values': ['backup', 'Backup']},
            ]
        ).get(
            'Reservations', []
        )

        instances = [
            i for r in reservations
            for i in r['Instances']
        ]

        print ('Found %d instances that need backing up') % len(instances)

        to_tag = collections.defaultdict(list)

        for instance in instances:
            try:
                retention_days = [
                    int(t.get('Value')) for t in instance['Tags']
                    if t['Key'] == 'Snap-Retention'][0]
            except IndexError:
                retention_days = 2

            for dev in instance['BlockDeviceMappings']:
                if dev.get('Ebs', None) is None:
                    continue
                vol_id = dev['Ebs']['VolumeId']
                print ("Found EBS volume %s on instance %s") % (
                    vol_id, instance['InstanceId'])

                snap = ec.create_snapshot(
                    VolumeId=vol_id,
                )

                to_tag[retention_days].append(snap['SnapshotId'])

                print ('Retaining snapshot %s of volume %s from instance %s for %d days') % (
                    snap['SnapshotId'],
                    vol_id,
                    instance['InstanceId'],
                    retention_days,
                )


        for retention_days in to_tag.keys():
            delete_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=retention_days)
            delete_fmt = delete_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            print ('Will delete %d snapshots on %s') % (len(to_tag[retention_days]), delete_fmt)
            ec.create_tags(
                Resources=to_tag[retention_days],
                Tags=[
                    {'Key': 'DeleteOn', 'Value': delete_fmt},
                ]
            )
```

The error:
[ERROR] TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 21, in lambda_handler
print ('Found %d instances that need backing up') % len(instances)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Please note that this is *not* a debugging support line.  If you don't know Python, the first thing you need to do is to learn enough to work with your own code.

Comment: Look at where you put the parentheses. `print()` doesn't return anything, so what is `print ('Found %d instances that need backing up') % len(instances)` supposed to do? In effect, it is `None % len(instances)`, which makes no sense. Beyond that hint, I second the recommendation of @Prune that you spend some time learning Python if you want to use it.

Comment: The base problem is well-documented -- we also expect you to research the problem before posting here.  You tried to do a modulus operation on a variable with an invalid value type: `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this line:

```
    print ('Found %d instances that need backing up') % len(instances)
```

You seem to be trying to format your output, but you closed off the `print` call before supplying a value.  Please refer to the documentation and tutorials on Python output formatting to get what you want, both here and in other places in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Don't convert the python script, use AWS Backup instead. AWS Backup automatically handles backups based on instance tags. You can set it up to be triggered at a certian time and all that. Since you are already specifying the backups here by tags on the instances it would be an easy switch and you wouldn't have to trouble shoot the Python script in the future.

https://aws.amazon.com/backup/